# Dynamic AJAX Content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I'm in need of a dynamic AJAX content code. I've found one from [dynamic drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm) but It's not the one I see on some websites. For example when I hover the link it shows: `ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external2.htm', 'rightcolumn');`

I don't want it to show that on hover. And also my PHP form doesn't process inside the ajax content box but it redirects to the page itself.

I've googled around (but still don't understand; i really suck in ajax :l) and there are some codes which I can manually add to my js file to process a particular form like (`#form-login`) or something, but I remember seeing a while back a source which doesnt require me to individually set a form yet it processes all PHP forms inside the ajax content area...

P.S. I'm looking for one that can dynamically load pages into my content box (including PHP Forms) without refreshing. And when I hover the link, it shows `#` instead of `ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external2.htm', 'rightcolumn');`.

I apologize if this is the wrong place to post this query and hope to hear from you guys soon!

Answer (score 2):

```
function test(id,type){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm",
    data:"id="+id+"&tp="+type,
    success: function(data){
       $('#playerRateSec').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how this works?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, if you can't read that above snippet of code and understand how to use it, you should probably take some time to learn JavaScript and jQuery. You need to lay a good foundation before you start building a mansion.  Understanding only the parts of the language that you want to use is a poor substitute for gaining literacy with a language.  Spend some time on Google going through tutorials and once you are comfortable, start working on your own project.

Comment: Yup I'm trying my very best to understand and learn the language but I just don't get it. Could you still explain the above code though? Thanks.

Comment: When we call this function for ex:    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test();">click me</a>   this function will run and get al data from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm        data came in success function in data variable at last we append data in a blank div <div id="playerRateSec"></div> from    $('#playerRateSec').html(data);